# Помогите решить спор с преподавателем по поводу моделей в EF Core

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Выполняю задание, нужно написать приложение с готовой БД на WPF с использованием EF Core.
Когда я показывал преподавателю предварительную версию, у нас возник спор.

Такой сгенерировался для EF Core.

```
public partial class ProductDB
{
    [Key]
    public string ProductArticleNumber { get; set; } = null!;

    public string ProductName { get; set; } = null!;

    public string ProductDescription { get; set; } = null!;

    public int ProductCategory { get; set; }

    public string? ProductPhoto { get; set; }

    public int ProductManufacturer { get; set; }

    public decimal ProductCost { get; set; }

    public sbyte? CurrentDiscount { get; set; }

    public int ProductQuantityInStock { get; set; }

    public int UnitOfMeasurement { get; set; }

    public int Delivery { get; set; }


    public int? ProductDiscountAmount { get; set; }

    public virtual Delivery DeliveryNavigation { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<Orderproduct> Orderproducts { get; } = new List<Orderproduct>();

    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategoryNavigation { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual Manufacturer ProductManufacturerNavigation { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual Unit UnitOfMeasurementNavigation { get; set; } = null!;

}
```

Так как мне нужно было добавить новые свойства, я создал новый класс

```
    public class Product
    {
        public string? Article { get; set; }
        public string? Title { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public string? Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public float? Price { get; set; }
        public int? MaxQuantity { get; set; }
        public float? CurrentDiscount { get; set; }



        public string Image { get; set; }


        public string ImageUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return Path.GetFullPath(@$"Resources\{Image}");
            }
        }


        public float? NewPrice
        {
            get
            {
                if (CurrentDiscount != 0)
                {
                    return Price - (Price * (CurrentDiscount / 100));
                }
                return 0;
            }
        }

        public bool HaveDiscount
        {
            get
            {
                return NewPrice != null;
            }
        }

    }
```

Препод сказал, что это излишнее дублирование кода. Я же считаю, что так правильнее, потому что один класс отвечает за связь с БД, а другой за работу внутри самой программы.

Буду рад если мне объяснят верное решение, и помогут решить спор.

Comment: То, что вы делаете, относится к MVVM подходу, где принято все разделять на мало связанные друг с другом слои. По такому подходу у проекта должны быть Model слои - это все то, что касается базы, ее классы, методы получения, и так далее. View - это UI приложения, всякие кнопочки, стили, и так далее. ViewModel - это связующий слой, который берет данные из M, заносит нужные данные в отдельные VM, которые содержат только нужные для работы UI свойства, обрабатывает привязанные команды, ну и так далее. Вот что излишне, так это названия в классе `ProductDB` по типу **Product**ArticleNumber))

Comment: Если говорить в рамках обучения, где вы не используете MVVM, а просто пишете код, то да, это излишне, бессмысленно. Ну а если ваш проект основан на MVVM, где вы изначально все разделяете, то такое разделение - это основа основ)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Как раз таки это задание и направлено на то, чтобы изучать еще и MVVM.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А можете сказать, правильно ли будет использовать наследование Product от ProductDB, чтобы свойства не дублировались?

Comment: Смотрите, ваш вопрос можно чуть иначе переформулировать, а точней "Допустимо-ли привязывать View сразу к Model". И вот тут уже мы встретим дилемму, ибо MVVM это рекомендации, а строгие требования, и каждый воспринимает их так, как хочет, как удобней конкретно данному разработчику, в данном проекте. Кто-то допускает привязку сразу к M, а кто-то нет. Например [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25714331/6808809), или [вот](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/123317), как видите, даже тут кто-то допускает такое, а кто-то нет.

Comment: Если мы говорим про строгое следование MVVM, то его правила гласят то, что между слоями должна быть минимальная связь, абстракция, где каждый слой не знает ничего про другие слои. То есть, Model должна быть независимой, не должна знать про V и VM, она должна лишь выполнять свою логику, и отдавать простые DTO/POCO. View слой также не должен ничего знать про модель, VM, и так далее, он просто существует, знает что есть свойства с определенными названиями, все. Так что, если строго следуем MVVM, то нет, наследовать нельзя, как и нельзя привязывать в View напрямую к VM, нужен промежуточный слой.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ опечатка, View нельзя привязывать в M, а не к VM.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Возможно вы меня не так поняли. Product и ProductDB обе модели. Мой вопрос заключается в том, нужно ли создавать другую модель, если у меня уже есть сгенерированная модель для работы с БД.

Comment: А, если это чисто модели, то наследуйте конечно, хоть `partial` делайте, это уже как вам удобно будет.